# Creating Visual Studio Solution Files Automatically

Tags: visual-studio

I have several Visual Studio .vcproj files which are auto generated, I would to automate the process of creation a solution file which includes all those .vcproj files.

Are there any command line tools which I can use the automate this as part of our build process?

P.S. It is possible to write some code to handle the necessary processing to handle this. However I am hoping for a MS provided commmand line tool which can handle various version of Visual Studio for now and the near future.

Comment: Doesn't Visual Studio create a solution when you open a project file?

Comment: The .sln file is a simple text file which is easy to generate. I doubt ms will provide a generic command line solution for this unless thousands of people will need to autogenerate sln files without opening VS.

Comment: Too few details. The fast suggestion: CMake?

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio does have [tools for generating GUIDs](http://blog.beckybertram.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=5489bebf-bd8d-4a6f-995b-3a0a456796f6&ID=74&Web=316c15c2-6bc0-464f-bda1-7ba96b4ba453). If you reverse engineer .sln and .vcproj files using a text editor, you'll know enough to put together a script that can write a solution file.

From [this link](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/VBNET/289626/289626/how-do-i-manually-create-my-solution-sln-file/), you get some clues about the project type GUID:

> The first GUID listed for each project is the type of project. For instance, a VB.NET project (vbproj) has this GUID: {F184B08F-C81C-45f6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}. You can find all the GUIDs that Visual Studio uses in the registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\7.1\Projects\
>
> The second GUID identifies the individual project. It corresponds to the GUID value found in the project listed in the solution file.

I'm about to give this a shot. Like someone said in the comments, this is a bit of a niche problem, so you may need to roll your own.